# combining two stored procedure to one stored procedure getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_PodiumSummeryCount]
   @locid integer = null
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
       sum(status_receved) as Receved, 
       sum(status_parked) as Parked,
       sum(status_requested) as Requested,
       sum(status_requestedinprocess) as Requestinprocess
    FROM 
       (SELECT 
            CASE WHEN (status = 0 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS status_receved,
            CASE WHEN (status = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS status_parked, 
            CASE WHEN (status = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS status_requested,
            CASE WHEN (status = 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS status_requestedinprocess
        FROM 
            transaction_tbl 
        WHERE 
            locid = @locid AND dtime >= getdate()-1 AND status IN (0,2,3,4)) a;

    SELECT 
       l1.StartTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 108) AS Time 
    FROM
       Location_tbl l1 
    WHERE 
       l1.Locid = @locid
END
```

I have one more stored procedure like this:

```
select  dbo.podiumsummerytime(
                convert(decimal(10,1),
                    avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.dtime, t.PAICdate  ))))

            ) as Avgparkingtime,
           dbo.podiumsummerytime(
                convert(decimal(10,1),
                    avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.Paydate, t.DelDate ))))

            ) as AvgDelivarytime,
            dbo.podiumsummerytime(
                convert(decimal(10,1),
                    avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.dtime, t.DelDate ))))

            ) as Avgstaytime

            from (select top 30 * from transaction_tbl where locid=@locid and dtime >= getdate()-2 order by transactID desc ) t
            end
```

I try to write this two stored procedure in one with union but I am getting error like this:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I am working with SQL Server 2008, how can I combine these two stored procedures into one stored procedure...

Comment: Your first stored procedure selects two datasets - one with **4**, the other with **2** columns in the output. The second stored procedure selects **3** columns - so **no**, you cannot combine these just like that - you'd have to settle on how to return your data in **one** dataset

Comment: so how i can return data in one set after joining these two stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the error says, UNION is a specific keyword use to get a set of rows with both results in. If the rows are different then they can't be joined with UNION.

There is nothing to stop you putting both queries in one stored procedure, The proc will then just return two result sets.

For example:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[IBS_PodiumSummeryCount]
    @locid integer = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Location = @Locid;

    SELECT * FROM Suppliers WHERE Location = @Locid;
END
```

Will return the results of both queries in separate results sets.

Comment: sir ,,is there any way to write this two stored procedure i can write in one stored procedure?

Comment: Just both select queries into the body of the stored procedure, I've added an example.

Comment: in my case i done want to get three set of result,,that i can make to two or one?

Comment: You cannot, each set of results has a particular shape, you can't put three different shapes into one.

Comment: in my code i can take second result somthing like dr.nextresult()..how i can take third result?

Comment: Another call to the same NextResult function will give you the third result.